# Recycler view item on click not working properly after searchview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have implemented recyclerview with searchview in my app. But on clicking the item after search, my app crashes.
My app works fine when item on list is clicked before search.
It only stops working when clicking search result.
[App Screen Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL481.gif)

My code for listview

```
class BookFragment : Fragment() , SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private var columnCount = 1
    private lateinit var bookViewModel: BookViewModel
    private val myAdapter: BookAdapter by lazy { BookAdapter(requireContext()) }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_book_list, container, false)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.mainList)
        val fab_add_button: FloatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.FAB_add_new)


        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        
        bookViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[BookViewModel::class.java]

        
        bookViewModel.allBooks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { books ->
            myAdapter.setBooks(books)
        }
        with(recyclerView) {
            adapter = myAdapter
            layoutManager = when {
                columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
            }

        }

        fab_add_button.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_bookFragment_to_addFragment)
        }


        postponeEnterTransition()
        recyclerView.doOnPreDraw {
            startPostponedEnterTransition()
        }
        return view
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu)

        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.list_menu_search)
        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)

    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.list_menu_setting -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_bookFragment_to_settingsFragment)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        if (query != null ) searchDB(query)
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        if (newText != null ) searchDB(newText)
        return true
    }

    private fun searchDB(string: String) {
        val query = "%$string%"
        bookViewModel.fetchSearchedBook(query).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { resp ->
            myAdapter.setBooks(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

My Adapter Code

```
class BookAdapter(context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var books = emptyList<LightNovel>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            SingleBookBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = books[position]
        holder.idView.text = item.id.toString()
        holder.contentView.text = item.title

        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(item.coverRemote)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_image_error)
            .into(holder.imageView)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
       holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_bookFragment_to_detailFragment)
            val action = BookFragmentDirections.actionBookFragmentToDetailFragment(item.id)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = books.size

    inner class ViewHolder(binding: SingleBookBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val idView: TextView = binding.itemNumber
        val contentView: TextView = binding.content
        val imageView: ImageView = binding.listCover
        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + " '" + contentView.text + "'"
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setBooks(lightNovels: List<LightNovel>) {
        this.books = lightNovels
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

And Detail Fragment

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private val args: DetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    private var _binding: FragmentDetailBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var bookViewModel: BookViewModel
    private lateinit var bookLN: LightNovel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val view = binding.root
        val bookid = args.bookID

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        bookViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[BookViewModel::class.java]

        bookViewModel
            .fetchLiveBook(bookid)
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                book ->
            bookLN = book
            binding.detailTitle.text = book.title

            val image = binding.detailCover
            val imageUrl = bookLN.coverRemote
            val valid = URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageUrl)
            if (valid) {
                Glide.with(requireContext())
                    .load(bookLN.coverRemote)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_image_error)
                    .into(image)
            }

            if (book.synopsis != null && book.synopsis.length >= 2) {
                binding.detailSynopsis.text = book.synopsis
            }

            if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(book.download)) {
            binding.detailButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED) }
            binding.detailButton.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(book.download))
                try {
                    startActivity(intent)

                } catch (_: ActivityNotFoundException) {

                }

            }
        }


        return view
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, menu)
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.detail_menu_update_book -> {
                val action = DetailFragmentDirections.actionDetailFragmentToUpdateFragment(args.bookID)
                findNavController().navigate(action)
            }

            R.id.detail_menu_delete_book -> {
                deleteBook(bookLN)
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun deleteBook(Ln: LightNovel) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setPositiveButton("Delete") {_,_ ->
            bookViewModel.deleteBook(Ln)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_detailFragment_to_bookFragment)

        }
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") {_,_ ->}
        builder.setTitle("Delete Entry?")
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ${Ln.title}")

        builder.create().show()


    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```

I think it might be due to `bookViewModel.fetchLiveBook(bookid)` not working. But I do not know where it is not working.

Logcat shows following

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.knight.moonreaderdatabase, PID: 21562
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner(Fragment.java:377)
                                                                                                        at com.knight.moonreaderdatabase.fragments.list.BookFragment.searchDB(BookFragment.kt:98)
                                                                                                        at com.knight.moonreaderdatabase.fragments.list.BookFragment.onQueryTextChange(BookFragment.kt:92)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1198)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1736)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10586)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6322)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6147)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:121)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6099)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.setQuery(SearchView.java:579)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onActionViewCollapsed(SearchView.java:1295)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter.collapseItemActionView(Toolbar.java:2656)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.collapseItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java:1384)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.clear(MenuBuilder.java:607)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2183)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:273)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:975)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:730)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:960)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Comment: For cases when your app crashes, it's always helpful if you add the error stacktrace from the logcat in the question.

Comment: please provide error message about your problem

Comment: there's no error message in logcat@@. open your logcat and do action crash in your device

Comment: error message my be this Process: com.knight.moonreaderdatabase, PID: 32045
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView():